# A confusing example of Noun Modifiers

Tags: nouns, modifiers

I have an example of Modification of Nouns in English from a realy valid book.It says there are two types of modifiers:adj. modifiers, and noun modifiers but it gives an example on both sides which is pretty puzzling:

Adjective Modifiers(modifiers are bolded):

He won a **gold*** medal in the **1000**-meter race in the **seventeenth** winter Olympics.

Noun Modifiers(modifiers are bolded):

He won a **gold*** medal in the 1000-**meter** race in the seventeenth **winter** Olympics.

Then it says,"The word gold can be considered a noun or an adjective, depending on wether it refers to the material or the color."

But after that it indicates that adj. modifiers have 11 types which are colors,material and 9 more.So can anyone tell me why the word gold could be a noun there?

Comment: Because gold is the substance of which the medal is made.

Comment: *Gold* can indeed be either noun or adjective, and can refer to either color or material, but the semantic options do not track perfectly as alleged with the syntactic ones.

Comment: What's the grammatical difference between a *wooden table* and a *wood table*? The word *wooden* is an adjective, and a material modifier. The word *wood* is a noun, but also a material modifier. The word *golden* is an adjective modifier, which can either refer to the color or the material.

Answer (score 2):

I think the book you have has expressed this point poorly.

In this case **gold** can be either a noun or adjective modifier, but as a noun modifier it is not really about the material that the medal is made from but what the material signifies, namely coming first. **Gold medal** is in that sense equivalent to **winners' medal** (i.e. first place) rather than either **gold-coloured medal** or **made-from-gold medal**. In **winners medal** we have a noun modifier, in the other two an adjective modifier.

Comment: In your proposed substitution, *winners* is more properly *winner's* (or *winners'),* which as a possessive or genitive is at least arguably a third kind of modifier for a noun, or perhaps not even a modifier as such.

Comment: You make a good point, @BrianDonovan. Perhaps what I mean is "winners'-type medal".